# Return async Closure in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I wan to return a asynchronous closure from a function in Rust.

The function that will late accept the closure as an argument (`for_each_concurrent`) expects something similar to `FnMut() -> dyn Future<Output = ()>` (but with some argument, that shouldn't matter).

I tried to create a function that returns a trait object [as described in the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-05-advanced-functions-and-closures.html).
But this will give me the error `expected trait object 'dyn Future', found 'async' block` along others. I don't know how to do this properly.

Here is a minimal example:

```
use std::future::Future;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let async_function = foo();
    async_function().await;
}

fn foo() -> Box<dyn FnMut() -> dyn Future<Output = ()>> {
    Box::new(|| async {
        // do async stuff
        print!("Hello, World!");
    })
}
```

While this works:

```
use std::future::Future;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let async_function = || async {
        // do async stuff
        print!("Hello, World!");
    };

    async_function().await;
}
```

I tried specifying the return type as async_block instead, but that is also impossible.
I also tried specifying the return type using `impl` instald of `Box<dyn ...>`.

Comment: You got it backward - you don't need to box the closure (you can return `impl FnMut`), but you do need to box the future it returns: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bd994d50ce883f21b20db3c9ccff75aa

Comment: ...and if you want to (or need to store the closure somewhere with its type erased), you can box both: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=873d0364aecb327f8f8122a31c7a48bb hint: `-> dyn Future` almost never makes sense, it needs to be `&dyn Future`, or `Box<dyn Future>`, `Rc<dyn Future>`, etc.

Comment: Yeah, `-> dyn` is 100% impossible. You can't make a function that returns an unsized type.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. The Boxing tip helped me out a lot, because I had to add some lifetime parameters which only worked with the outer box.

Comment: I want to learn more about async rust, can you recommend some resources @user4815162342?